# Customize the caption with a background

Tags: color, captions, listings, tcolorbox, minted

[image]

Hi there, i have some problems with modifying a caption which belongs to a listing.

The current result is shown in picture.

What i would like to change, can be seen in the second picture.

[image]

As you can hopefully see, I'd like to place `Listing 1: Nicht implementierte Funktion` at the left margin.
Furthermore I'd like to write the caption in a colorbox. (in the second picture the caption `Listing 1: Nicht implementierte Funktion` has also a grey background) This colorbox should have the size from the left to the right margin (same as the listing)

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
 frame code={}
 center title,
 left=0pt,
 right=0pt,
 top=0pt,
 bottom=0pt,
 colback=gray!70,
 colframe=white,
 width=\dimexpr\textwidth\relax,
 enlarge left by=0mm,
 boxsep=0pt,
 arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage{caption}

\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{code}
 \captionof{listing}{Nicht implementierte Funktion}
 \label{code:comp area listing}
 \begin{minted}[linenos, bgcolor=bg]{python}
def komplizierte_funktion(a, b):
    raise NotImplementedError('Noch nicht implementiert.')
 \end{minted}
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably define a new tcblisting. You are using `tcolorbox` and `minted` already. You can combine their powers and of course still add labels and reference them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[minted,most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}

% `blend into = listings' can only be used after begin document

\begin{document}

\newtcblisting[blend into = listings]{code}[1][]{
  listing engine = minted ,
  listing only ,
  minted language = python ,
  minted options = { linenos } ,
  colback = bg ,
  coltitle = black ,
  colframe = gray!70 ,
  fonttitle = \large ,
  left = 6mm,
  lefttitle = 0mm,
  leftrule = 0pt,
  rightrule = 0pt,
  bottomrule = 0pt,
  arc = 0pt,
  #1
}

\begin{code}[title=Nicht implementierte Funktion,label=code:comp area listing]
def komplizierte_funktion(a, b):
    raise NotImplementedError('Noch nicht implementiert.')
\end{code}

See Listing~\ref{code:comp area listing} as an example for\dots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot! Is it possible to change the size of the title text `Nicht implementierte Funktion`?

Comment: @Domi1908 yes, sure. I modified the example adding an example for `fonttitle` and also added a label and a reference

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to my proposal:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}

\usemintedstyle{perldoc}
\setlength\partopsep{-\topsep}

\usepackage{caption,newfloat}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lol]{lstlisting}[Listing][List of Listings]
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{box=colorbox,boxcolor=gray, justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, labelfont=bf, font=it}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\caption{This is the title I want for my code}
\vspace{-0.65cm}
 \begin{minted}[linenos, bgcolor=bg]{python}
def komplizierte_funktion(a, b):
    raise NotImplementedError('Noch nicht implementiert.')
 \end{minted}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great. Is it possible also to write the line numbers INSIDE the box?

Answer (score 0):

Just add more options to `\captionsetup`:
`justification=` to specify justification.
`singlelinecheck=0` as without it the caption is re-centered afterwards.

more info: caption documentation, pp 9-10

````
\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing,justification=RaggedRight,singlelinecheck=0}}{}```
````

Comment: Okay but i dont see the possibility how to add a background color to the caption.